# ¿Cómo obtener un listado de registro con especificaciones individuales de limit MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysqli

Quiero generar una evaluación de 120 preguntas todas estas preguntas las tengo en una sola tabla de datos, esta es mi estructura de la tabla de datos.

```
id_question     question     a1     a2     a3     a4     answer     category
.........
```

He agregado una columna llamada category (categoría), donde he especificado cada registro de una pregunta de que materia es la pregunta.

Ahora yo entiendo que mediante `WHERE` Y `AND` puedo traer datos especifico de una columna de una tabla de datos.

Por ejemplo

```
 WHERE category=metematica AND categoría=qimica AND...
```

Pero cómo se le indica al `limit` cuantas preguntas traer de cada `AND` de cada categoría...

Lo que deseo lograr es generar 120 preguntas en total obteniendo un total de preguntas personalizadas por cada materia es decir: de la primer materia 40 preguntas, de la segunda materia 30 preguntas, de la tercera materia 40 preguntas, de la cuarta materia 20 preguntas, de la quinta materia 20 preguntas y así según la evaluación.

Para ello he preparado las siguientes variables:

```
$categoty_one = "matematicas"; // 40 preguntas
$categoty_two = "lenguaje"; // 30 preguntas
$categoty_three = "ciencias"; // 40 preguntas
$categoty_four = "historia"; // 20 preguntas
$categoty_five = "quimica"; //20 preguntas
```

Pero como género las 120 preguntas, teniendo en cuenta lo descrito.

Este es mi código:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE enabled=yes";
$result = $con->query($sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $answers[] = [
        'name' => 'respuesta_'.$row["id_question"],
        'question' => $row["question"],
        'alternatives' => [$row["a1"], $row["a2"],$row["a3"],$row["a4"]],
        'answer' => $row["answer"]
    ];
}

$questions = [];

foreach($answers as $index => $answer) {
    $questions[]=$answer;
    $questions[$index]['answer']=null;
}
```

También es de suma importancia que al momento de traer ciertas preguntas venga en orden es decir que no esté mezclado una pregunta de matemáticas y la siguiente pregunta en química, todo debe ser ordenado.

Answer (score 2):

```
$answers = [];
$conex = new mysql('localhost','root','','db');
$limits = ['matematicas' => '40','lenguaje' => '30','ciencias' => '40','historia' => '20','quimica' => '20'];

foreach ($limits as $key => $value) {

        $consul = $conex->query('SELECT * FROM preguntas WHERE categoría='.$key.' limit('.$value.')');

        $consul = $conex->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        foreach ($consul as $row) {
             $answers[] = [
                        'name' => 'respuesta_'.$row["id_question"],
                        'question' => $row["question"],
                        'alternatives' => [$row["a1"], $row["a2"],$row["a3"],$row["a4"]],
                        'answer' => $row["answer"]
                    ];
        }
}
```

Esto te puede servir.
Lo que se hace es crear un array con las materias que necesitas y con un ciclo foreach hacer el recorrido a ese array y despues otro recorrido para recorre la consulta que se hace en mysqli y pues ya tienes lista en $answers con todas las respuestas

y pues estan en order de consulta osea de categoria a medida que se van cultando se van ingresando en el array answers

Comment: solo responder con código se considera de baja calidad; dale editar y añade una explicación

Answer (score 1):

Puedes escribir sub-consultas cada una con su `WHERE` y su `LIMIT` y unirlas con `UNION`.

Por ejemplo, aquí te traerá: 3 preguntas de Matemáticas, 2 de Lenguaje, 4 de Ciencias, 5 de Historia y 1 de Química:

```
(SELECT * FROM jacks_questions WHERE category = 'Matemáticas' LIMIT 3)
 UNION
(SELECT * FROM jacks_questions WHERE category = 'Lenguaje'    LIMIT 2)
 UNION
(SELECT * FROM jacks_questions WHERE category = 'Ciencias'    LIMIT 4)
 UNION
(SELECT * FROM jacks_questions WHERE category = 'Historia'    LIMIT 5)
 UNION
(SELECT * FROM jacks_questions WHERE category = 'Química'     LIMIT 1);
```

**Resultado:**

```
id_question          question       category
---------------------------------------------------
1                    Question 01    Matemáticas
3                    Question 03    Matemáticas
5                    Question 05    Matemáticas
2                    Question 02    Lenguaje
10                   Question 10    Lenguaje
4                    Question 04    Ciencias
11                   Question 11    Ciencias
13                   Question 13    Ciencias
20                   Question 20    Ciencias
6                    Question 06    Historia
7                    Question 07    Historia
8                    Question 08    Historia
15                   Question 15    Historia
17                   Question 17    Historia
12                   Question 12    Química
```

---

#### Demostración en línea

<kbd>**[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](https://rextester.com/EAN9035)**</kbd>